# User write to C from CMD

Tags: windows-7, users, windows-command-prompt

I have a very strange problem. On some computers in my network I can go to C:\ directory, run edit program and save file to C:. But when I list files in directory this file is not listed. But when I open the same file with edit program I can see saved content.

What is going on here?

I have a legacy program that needs to write to C:\ and even though users can't create files on C drive from explorer they can use this dos application just fine.

On other computers where I can't save to C:\ from dos (or whatever is going on in the first group) the program is causing me problems.

So how can I achieve same behavior on second group of computers? All users are just domain users and are not administrators.

So "icalcs.exe c:" on machine where program works:
BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(AD)
Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level:(OI)(NP)(IO)(NW)

And on machine where it doesn't work:
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(S,AD)
Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level:(OI)(NP)(IO)(NW)

Also when I log on to the computer where application works as Admin, I can't see file created on directory C: by domain user. But if I log on as a User again the file is still not visible but with command "edit C:\bla.txt" the content I saved in that file appears (but command "notepad C:\bla.txt" says there is no file C:\bla.txt).

Comment: You need to include the text output of `icacls.exe C:\` from a computer where the app works and one where it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean literally putting files in the root of the C:? Like `C:\mytax_~1.csv`?

That's a big no-no for at least the last 10, maybe 15 years. So it's no surprise that you have some process that can't do this, especially if you actually have what you claim (a genuine DOS program).

My guess would be that on your machines that *can* do this, maybe they have UAC turned off, or some sort of more liberal permissions.

It certainly *sounds* like the user has read/write permissions for the drive, but not list files permission. I would certainly start by investigating your NTFS permissions.